ModalNavigationDrawer ignores PointerInputChange
Look at the following GIF. When the checkbox is checked, the green area (Column in MaxBox) detects swipes from right to left. Each such swipe increments the counter by one. When the checkbox is unchecked, the Column stops the detection.
In both states, the user should be able to open the navigation drawer by swiping from left to right but for some reason, when the checkbox is checked, the navigation drawer doesn't detect any gestures even though the Column doesn't consume any PointerInputChange events.

Here is the code:
MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            App()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun App() {
    val counter = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    NavigationDrawer(restContent = {
        MaxBox(onSwipe = {
            counter.intValue++
        }) {
            Text(
                fontSize = 32.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                text = "${counter.intValue}",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }
    }) {
        Text(text = "Drawer content", fontSize = 34.sp)
    }
}

MaxBox.kt
@Composable
fun MaxBox(
    onSwipe: () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable (() -> Unit)
) {
    val swipeState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = Color(0xFF608060))
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(horizontal = 24.dp, vertical = 48.dp)
    ) {
        // This is the composable on which the swiping detection (right to left) is applied
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .let { old ->
                if (swipeState.value) {
                    return@let old.swipe(
                        onSwipe,
                        direction = SwipeDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT
                    )
                } else return@let old
            }
        ) {
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Text(
                    color = Color.White,
                    fontSize = 32.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    text = "Swipe from right"
                )

                Checkbox(checked = swipeState.value, onCheckedChange = { value ->
                    swipeState.value = value
                })
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))

            content()
        }
    }
}

NavigationDrawer.kt
// Basic wrapper around ModalNavigationDrawer
@Composable
fun NavigationDrawer(
    restContent: @Composable (() -> Unit),
    navigationContent: @Composable (() -> Unit)
) {
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)

    ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            ModalDrawerSheet {
                navigationContent()
            }
        }
    ) {
        restContent()
    }
}

SwipeModifier.kt
enum class SwipeDirection {
    BOTTOM_TO_TOP,
    LEFT_TO_RIGHT,
    RIGHT_TO_LEFT,
    TOP_TO_BOTTOM
}

fun SwipeDirection.getOffset(offset: Offset) = if (isHorizontal()) offset.x else offset.y

fun SwipeDirection.isHorizontal() =
    this == SwipeDirection.LEFT_TO_RIGHT || this == SwipeDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT

fun SwipeDirection.isNegative() =
    this == SwipeDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT || this == SwipeDirection.BOTTOM_TO_TOP

private class SwipeHandler(
    private val direction: SwipeDirection,
    private val sensitivityFraction: Float,
    private val onSwipe: () -> Unit
) {
    private val boxSize = mutableFloatStateOf(0f)
    private val consumeMethod: (Offset) -> Boolean = { offset ->
        consumeOffset(direction.getOffset(offset), direction.isNegative())
    }
    private val dragAmount = mutableFloatStateOf(0f)
    private var hasSwiped = mutableStateOf(false)

    fun onDragStart(o: Offset) {
        dragAmount.floatValue = 0f
        hasSwiped.value = false
    }

    fun onDrag(change: PointerInputChange, offset: Offset) {
        if (hasSwiped.value)
            return

        val isConsumed = consumeMethod(offset)

        if (isConsumed)
            change.consume() // Event is consumed here
        else return // Events in the opposing direction are not consumed

        val sens = boxSize.floatValue * sensitivityFraction
        val dragExceededSensitivity = abs(dragAmount.floatValue) >= sens

        if (dragExceededSensitivity) {
            onSwipe()
            hasSwiped.value = true
        }
    }

    private fun consumeOffset(amount: Float, isNegative: Boolean): Boolean {
        if (isNegative) {
            if (amount >= 0.0f)
                return false // Do not consume this event
        } else if (amount <= 0.0f)
            return false // Do not consume this event

        dragAmount.floatValue += amount
        return true // Consume this event
    }

    fun onDragEnd() {
        hasSwiped.value = false
    }

    fun onSizeChanged(size: IntSize) {
        boxSize.floatValue = if (direction.isHorizontal()) size.width.toFloat()
        else size.height.toFloat()
    }
}

// This modifier is applied on the Column when the checkbox is checked
fun Modifier.swipe(
    onSwipe: () -> Unit,
    direction: SwipeDirection = SwipeDirection.LEFT_TO_RIGHT,
    sensitivityFraction: Float = 0.25f
): Modifier = composed {
    val handler = remember(direction, onSwipe, sensitivityFraction) {
        SwipeHandler(direction, sensitivityFraction, onSwipe)
    }

    this
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures(
                onDragStart = handler::onDragStart,
                onDrag = { change, offset -> handler.onDrag(change, offset) },
                onDragEnd = handler::onDragEnd
            )
        }
        .onSizeChanged { size -> handler.onSizeChanged(size) }
}

What code should be changed to allow the user to open the navigation drawer by swiping from left to right in both states of the checkbox?
